# How to write c code without any letters, but you can use only main word?

Tags: c++, c, obfuscation

I searched for  obfuscation code, but didnt find examples how to write code without any word. Even without #define, int, etc...
There is a way to do this, but i cant find...

Comment: What is unclear about this question?  This kind of silly obfuscation could be referred to as *illiterate programming*.

Comment: `main() { }` is a valid program.

Comment: @jamesdlin The program should do something more, than nothing, at least it should display some characters on a display.

Comment: Given that all language keywords involve at least one letter, there isn't much scope for a solution to this question to achieve much ... if any - behaviour or output.

Comment: @prots These sort of details are why your question, as asked, is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to illiterate programming!

There is one way to do this: create a file with just white space and possibly some comments without any letters.  This file can be compiled as C code, and will produce an empty object file, not very useful I'm afraid...

You could also abuse the preprocessor and use only digits and the underscore. By compiling your code with a well chosen command line option to include a key file before the source file, you could avoid all letters.  You would need to use macros for all keywords and types, and also the `main` function name.  Contorted but doable. You might want to write a program to perform the obfuscation automatically.

For example:

**key.h:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _1 int
#define _2 main
#define _3 printf
#define _4 return
```

**source.c:**

```
_1 _2() {
    _3("\110\145\154\154\157\040\167\157\162\154\144\041\012");
    _4 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this with:

```
gcc -include key.h source.c -o program
./program
```

should produce:

```
Hello world!
```

**EDIT:** If you cannot use a key file, define the macros on the command line:

```
gcc -include stdio.h -D_1=int -D_2=main -D_3=printf -D_4=return source.c -o program
./program
```

Comment: This still uses letters ("include", "define", "int", "printf", "return", ...).

Comment: @jamesdlin: only in the key file. All letters can be removed from the source files.  The key file does not contain any code.

Comment: @chqrlie This is easy to find. But i cant use key file. And i cant even use any letters anywhere. Just single word main is valid 1 time.

Comment: @prots: see my updated answer.

Comment: @chqrlie Unfortunatly, i cant even use predifinition like this